# Getting map's key and value

Tags: aerospike

I'm using C client library to fetch a map from Aerospike. I got the [code](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/c/d5/d8d/structas__hashmap__iterator.html) to implement the map iterator:

```
as_hashmap_iterator it;
as_hashmap_iterator_init(&it, &map);
while ( as_hashmap_iterator_has_next(&it) )
 {
    const as_val * val = as_hashmap_iterator_next(&it);
 }
```

however, I don't know how to fetch the key and value from as_val? Are there any functions like as_map_get_key(iterator) and as_map_get_value(iterator)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast it to (as_pair*). You can refer to [this bit of code](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-c/blob/bda70092be0b3e14c24b4debe96dd52f45c2a485/src/test/aerospike_udf/udf_types.c#L427).

This was cross posted [here](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/using-all-values-in-as-map-as-hashmap/5254) as well.